# Browsing and selecting a file in windows on click of a button using JavaScipt

Tags: javascript

I know there are other ways of creating a button in JavaScript but below code works for me. However, can somebody help me on how I can make this clickable and browse a file inside Windows and select that file?

Also, this button is positioned at lower left part of the screen. I would appreciate if you can teach me how I can make it somewhere middle or how to position it properly.

Pardon my lack of knowledge in JavaScript, I just started learning 2 days ago :) Thank you very much in advance.

```js
// ==UserScript==
// @name         Test Tampermonkey Script
// @version      0.1
// @description  Test
// @author       Me
// @match        https://test.com/*
// @grant        GM_xmlhttpRequest
// @grant        GM_info
// ==/UserScript==
(function() {
    'use strict';

    /*--- Create a button in a container div.  It will be styled and
    positioned with CSS.
    */
    var zNode = document.createElement('div');
    zNode.innerHTML = '<button id="myButton" type="button">' +
        'Browse a file:</button>';

    zNode.setAttribute('id', 'myContainer');
    document.body.appendChild(zNode);

    //--- Activate the newly added button.
    document.getElementById("myButton").addEventListener(
        "click", ButtonClickAction, false
    );

})();
```

Comment: Selecting files from a web page (that is, a page shown in a browser) is done with the `<input>` element with the "type" attribute set to "file".

Comment: You have missed to include the definition of ButtonClickAction function. This should be another function/method that will be invoked when the button is clicked. Open browser dev tools and check the console tab to identify any JS errors. For positioning the button, you can add below styles on the container div(having id myContainer)

`display: flex; justify-content: center;`

Comment: You need to use a `<input>` field with the type as `file`. Resource you can refer to: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's be clear...

If you need to just let the user choose from his files and give you one or more of them, you can just use the `input` with `type="file"` and it will do the full job to you, and if you need to have a full access throw the file system of the user and navigate through it yourself from the root directory, then you can use the `file system` api which you can file more information about it here: [MDN FileSystem API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileSystem)

---

Now let's talk about the first idea which I think it's what you need.

You need a button to click, and when clicking, the user needs to be able to choose a file from his computer, and when he finish choosing a file, you will take this file and use it.

First you will create three elements, a label contains a button and an input, and the input will be hidden but the button will be shown:

```
function createButton() {
    let label = document.createElement("label")

    let input = document.createElement("input")
    input.setAttribute("type", "file")
    input.style.display = "none"
    input.addEventListener("change", getFile)

    let button = document.createElement("button")
    button.innerText = "Browse a file:"
    button.addEventListener("click", () => input.click())

    label.append( input, button )

    document.body.append( label )
}
```

Now you have the button in your web page, and it's ready to listen for changes, now let's create the `getFile` function that will be run whenever the input changes:

```
function getFile( evt ) {
    let reader = new FileReader()
    reader.onload = () => {
        let url = reader.result
        // now you have access to the url of the file
        // you can use it as you want
    }
    reader.readAsDataURL( evt.target.files[0] )
}
```

And now you have access to the url of the file entered to you from the user.. and you can use it as you want..

Now let's create a real working one to try here.

We will build an image uploader here:

```js
createButton()

function createButton() {
    let label = document.createElement("label")

    let input = document.createElement("input")
    input.setAttribute("type", "file")
    input.style.display = "none"
    input.addEventListener("change", getFile)

    let button = document.createElement("button")
    button.innerText = "Browse a file:"
    button.addEventListener("click", () => input.click())

    label.append( input, button )

    document.body.append( label )
}

function getFile( evt ) {
    let reader = new FileReader()
    reader.onload = () => {
        let url = reader.result
        let img = document.createElement("img")
        img.src = url
        img.style.width = "150px"
        img.style.height = "100px"
        img.style.objectFit = "contain"
        img.style.objectPosition = "center"
        document.body.append(img)
    }
    reader.readAsDataURL( evt.target.files[0] )
}
```

Now you can run this code and try the result.

Comment: Hi @Ahmed, thank you for the suggestion and for the codes. I'm able to browse the file and select. However, what happen is, I am able to browse a file multiple times and able to select and multiple files (square icons). How can I only attach 1 file? Also, my goal is when I select a file, I need to move it to another location. Thank you very much for the support.

Comment: @JoeCastro the `input` with `type="file"` is just an interface that the browser use to provide you a file, you have no access to the user file system, you don't even have the ability to know the path of the file. However if you need to control the user's filesystem, copy, move, delete, and create files in his computer, then you must use the `FileSystem` API. But I don't have enough knowledge in filesystem api, I'm still learning it, so you can take a look at this article and the one I linked in the answer: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File_and_Directory_Entries_API